# AngJs $http.post giving 202 in IE but working in Chrome for posting in https

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, wcf, ssl, https

AngularJs $http.post works fine with http (Non-SSL) post request 
But for https requests (SSL-Enabled) it gives 202.
I have tried setting the common `Accept` or `Content-Type` `headers` as suiggested by many

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', [], function ($httpProvider) {
            //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = { 'Accept': '*/*' };
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" };
        });
```

the http post are using shortcut methods

```
var l_url = "https://.../ABC.svc/Get";
            var Data = {};
            var res = $http.post(l_url, Data);
            res.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            });
            res.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {             
            });
```

Below is the request headers

```
 Key    Value
    Request POST /WCF/abc.svc/Get HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
    Referer https://..../abc.aspx
    Accept-Language en-US
    Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
    User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
    Host    webapps.adterminals.ae
    Content-Length  2
    Connection  Keep-Alive
    Cookie  __utma=4766435.232713021.1427716113.1432028677.1437554384.8; __utmz=4766435.1427716113.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _ga=GA1.2.232713021.1427716113; ASP.NET_SessionId=mshdtgl1hy0dctzumrl1tt3q; __utmc=4766435; .ASPXAUTH=D3E9D4B2C3BA24CE4F787D90745E97D2FED3C3E601CB3AF2C4168885084D4A97396749D85C5CD59245A42FBF4F95B539F2D0AAD8F27BD0721D07BDA4FB7B4360B56077A334F3E4E409815E4189935B8A02E2D356F34B9C111EB463A0949E4B1915E6872BF7336131179E6D67C297ECED2EB13F3BC2BCB59F96FCA80C8FE794E6
```

Below are the response headers

```
Key Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible IE=Edge
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept
Access-Control-Request-Method   POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    POST,GET,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age  1728000
Date    Wed, 22 Jul 2015 10:02:21 GMT
Content-Length  0
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is that correct that the same code is working in Chrome?

Comment: same means I have obfuscated the actual service name , yes it works in chrome

Comment: Have you compared the request headers and post data between Chrome and IE? 202 code from IIS usually means an error.

Comment: You were correct , the error was due to extra cookies added from Internet Explorer , but no where did it throw the error and gave 202 , which made it difficult to figure out.